# Searching if the values on a list is in the dictionary whose format is key-string, value-list(strings)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

```
my_dict = {                              # This dictionary is generated thru
'a' : [ 'value1', 'value4', 'value5' ],  # the info given by the user
'b' : [ 'value2', 'value6', 'value7'],
'c' : [ 'value3', 'value8', 'value9']
}

list = [ 'value1', 'value2' ] # List is generated using list comprehension
```

I need to generate a list that will output something like this:

```
output_list = ['a', 'b']
```

I need to check if the values on "list" matches with the values on the list inside of the dictionary. Is this even possible?

I tried to use this but I only get an empty list:

```
[key for key, value in my_dict.items() if value in list]
```

Comment: Your comprehension evaluates to `if  [ 'value1', 'value4', 'value5' ] in list` btw

Comment: Thank you for that comment Ian!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `list` as well (and you should not be using `list` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in `list` function) . Example -

```
[key for item in lst for key,value in my_dict.items() if item in value]
```

Demo -

```
>>> my_dict = {                              # This dictionary is generated thru
... 'a' : [ 'value1', 'value4', 'value5' ],  # the info given by the user
... 'b' : [ 'value2', 'value6', 'value7'],
... 'c' : [ 'value3', 'value8', 'value9']
... }
>>>
>>> lst = [ 'value1', 'value2' ]
>>> [key for item in lst for key,value in my_dict.items() if item in value]
['a', 'b']
```

---

You can get better performance, if you use `set` instead of `list` to store the values in the dictionary (since searching inside a set is O(1) operation, whereas searching inside a list is O(n) ). Example -

```
my_dict = {key:set(value) for key,value in my_dict.items()}
[key for item in lst for key,value in my_dict.items() if item in value]
```

Demo -

```
>>> my_dict = {key:set(value) for key,value in my_dict.items()}
>>> pprint(my_dict)
{'a': {'value4', 'value5', 'value1'},
 'b': {'value6', 'value7', 'value2'},
 'c': {'value3', 'value9', 'value8'}}
>>> lst = [ 'value1', 'value2' ]
>>> [key for item in lst for key,value in my_dict.items() if item in value]
['a', 'b']
```

---

If you are trying to check if any of the values in the list match with any value from the list in the dictionary, you can use `set.intersection`  and check if the result is empty or not. Example -

```
[key for key, value in my_dict.items() if set(value).intersection(lst)]
```

This result will not be ordered, since dictionary does not have any specific order.

Demo -

```
>>> my_dict = {
... 'a' : [ 'value1', 'value4', 'value5' ],
... 'b' : [ 'value2', 'value6', 'value7'],
... 'c' : [ 'value3', 'value8', 'value9']
... }
>>> lst = [ 'value1', 'value2' ]
>>> [key for key, value in my_dict.items() if set(value).intersection(lst)]
['b', 'a']
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Kumar! Thank you very much for your response. It worked. I just didn't get what you meant by O(1) operation for set and O(n) for list. Please enlighten me. I'm still a newbie at Python. Thank you!

Comment: O(1) operation means that it would be completed in constant time, the time required to search for an item inside a set does not depend on the size of the set. Comparing that to O(n) , O(n) means that the time required to search for an item in list depends on the size of the list, so as size increases it would take more time to search for the item in it.

Comment: Wow. That means a lot. Thank you. Can I do a follow up question here regarding the code? What if instead of a list, I have a string that needs to be compared to the values in the list in the dictionary?

Comment: How do you need to compare the values of the string? I mean an example for the string and what you would expect as output.

Comment: I figured it out Mr. Kumar. Same output as above. A list that contains all the keys that contains the same string values as the user input. I used this: [key for key, value in my_dict.items() if user_input in value]

Comment: Hi Mr. Kumar. I have a follow up question. What if I only need to compare the values in lst with those items in index 1 of each list in the dictionary?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90710/discussion-between-juan-dela-cruz-and-anand-s-kumar).